# Trying to propagate a select2 dropdown from an API in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, jquery-select2

I am having trouble propagating a selct2 dropdown from data from an API.
I am using this example from here

https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax

as well as from here

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/is-it-possible-to-populate-a-select-drop-down-menu-from-an-external-api

Basically, my select2 dropdown is showing, but it is empty.

Here is my select 2 HTML code

```
<select class="form-control" name="shortcode" id="formControlSelectShortCode" required>
```

Here is my script

```
   $('#formControlSelectShortCode').select2({
    ajax: {
        url: 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories',
        dataType: 'json'
      }
    });
```

I used the 2 pages above as a reference, but the code looks ok from what i can see. it might be an issue with the api, however, the sample on the page works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full code for select2 dropdown from exaple you provided.

https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax#additional-examples

You are missing providing search parameter q since github's api returns error message if q is not provided.

Comment: Hi zivkovicf, I tried the sample code, but same thing, the select2 is empty. I made sure to change the first line from $(".js-example-data-ajax").select2({ to $('#formControlSelectShortCode').select2({ so it matched my select2 dropdown id, but still no propagation.

Comment: Did you include all parameters from example aswell? because you need to provide search param for api to work. Dropdown itself will always be empty if no text is provided.

Comment: I basically copied the whole example code. I just made the changes to the first line by adding the # and making sure it referenced the ID in the dropdown.

Comment: Have you installed select2 package using bower or npm, or You can include CDN links in you head part like described in installation guide [here](https://select2.org/getting-started/installation)

Comment: Hi zivkovicf, yes, I've installed select2 by including the CDN links in the view. I'm going to try spitting out some debug logs in the script to see if the data is there and if so, what form it's in. I'll report back here. Thanks for your ideas and help thus far.